# Is PhotoChooserTask still supported in Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal App)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Is PhotoChooserTask still supported?

When I try to add the Microsoft.Phone.dll, I get the following error at build time:[image]

This is a rather difficult error to debug (at least for me), shouldn't it just prevent you from referencing the assembly if it is no longer supported in Universal Apps? If this is because it is a Silverlight assembly, how am I supposed to realize this?

[PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask.aspx) documentation on MSDN indicates that it is supported by Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Phone App/Universal App, You can't use PhotoChooserTask any more.

You can use ***FileOpenPicker*** to access image from *`PictureLibrary`*.

Here is an example: [Pick an image in windows phone 8.1](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/nokia-imaging-sdk/quick-start/qs-w81-wp81.html)

Comment: I did discover that, but I wasn't able to find ANYTHING that mentioned that PhotoChooserTask is no longer supported :(